# How to shift substring in next row in SQL DB2

Tags: sql, db2

I have one column with sub string
I want to shift sub string after ' - ' in next row using db2 sql
how can I do it?I want to do it same as on one or more column
 anyone have any solution on same?

**col1**

```
|abc_pqr|
|lmn_abc|
```

**output**

```
|abc|
|pqr|
|lmn|
|abc|
```

here is my query

```
(SELECT DISTINCT T1.PROJECT_NAME,
       T1.REFERENCE_ID,
       T1.NAME AS URL1_title,
       T1.URL AS URL1,
       T1.REQUEST_TYPE,
       T2.VAL||'_'||T3.VAL AS  value1

FROM RIDW.VW_REQUEST T1
LEFT OUTER JOIN RICALM.VW_RQST_STRING_EXT T2
ON T2.REQUEST_ID=T1.REQUEST_ID AND T2.NAME='owner_1'
  LEFT OUTER JOIN RICALM.VW_RQST_STRING_EXT T3
  ON T3.REQUEST_ID=T1.REQUEST_ID AND T3.NAME='owner_2'
WHERE T1.PROJECT_ID = 0  AND
(  T1.REQUEST_TYPE = 'Task' 
) AND
(T1.ISSOFTDELETED = 0) AND
(T1.REQUEST_ID <> -1 AND T1.REQUEST_ID IS NOT NULL))a

union all
select substr(a.value1,locate(a.value1,'_')+1) from 

(SELECT DISTINCT T1.PROJECT_NAME,
       T1.REFERENCE_ID,
       T1.NAME AS URL1_title,
       T1.URL AS URL1,
       T1.REQUEST_TYPE,
       T2.VAL||'_'||T3.VAL AS  value1

FROM RIDW.VW_REQUEST T1
LEFT OUTER JOIN RICALM.VW_RQST_STRING_EXT T2
ON T2.REQUEST_ID=T1.REQUEST_ID AND T2.NAME='owner_1'
  LEFT OUTER JOIN RICALM.VW_RQST_STRING_EXT T3
  ON T3.REQUEST_ID=T1.REQUEST_ID AND T3.NAME='owner_2'
WHERE T1.PROJECT_ID = 0  AND
(  T1.REQUEST_TYPE = 'Task' 
) AND
(T1.ISSOFTDELETED = 0) AND
(T1.REQUEST_ID <> -1 AND T1.REQUEST_ID IS NOT NULL))a
```

I know I missed something in above query

Comment: There is no such thing as a "next row" in a relational database.  Tables represent *unordered* sets.

Comment: I am new for db2 ,i have one more query is it possible  in new column?

Comment: only one underscore or multiple underscores??

Comment: my scenario is that string after underscore set in new row in new col@Rams

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select substr(a.o1,1,LOCATE_IN_STRING(a.o1,'_')-1) as qwert from 

(SELECT DISTINCT T1.PROJECT_NAME,
       T1.REFERENCE_ID,
       T1.NAME AS URL1_title,
       T1.URL AS URL1,
       T1.REQUEST_TYPE,
       T2.VAL||'_' ||T3.VAL||'_'|| T4.VAL AS o1     
FROM RIDW.VW_REQUEST T1
LEFT OUTER JOIN RICALM.VW_RQST_STRING_EXT T2
ON T2.REQUEST_ID=T1.REQUEST_ID AND T2.NAME='owner_1'
  LEFT OUTER JOIN RICALM.VW_RQST_STRING_EXT T3
  ON T3.REQUEST_ID=T1.REQUEST_ID AND T3.NAME='owner_2'
    LEFT OUTER JOIN RICALM.VW_RQST_STRING_EXT T4
    ON T4.REQUEST_ID=T1.REQUEST_ID AND T4.NAME='owner_3'
WHERE T1.PROJECT_ID = 0  AND
(  T1.REQUEST_TYPE = 'Task' 
) AND
(T1.ISSOFTDELETED = 0) AND
(T1.REQUEST_ID <> -1 AND T1.REQUEST_ID IS NOT NULL))a

union all

select substr(b.o1,LOCATE_IN_STRING(b.o1,'_')+1,LOCATE_IN_STRING(b.o1,'_')-1) as qwert from 
(SELECT DISTINCT T1.PROJECT_NAME,
       T1.REFERENCE_ID,
       T1.NAME AS URL1_title,
       T1.URL AS URL1,
       T1.REQUEST_TYPE,
              T2.VAL||'_'||T3.VAL||'_'||T4.VAL AS o1    
FROM RIDW.VW_REQUEST T1
LEFT OUTER JOIN RICALM.VW_RQST_STRING_EXT T2
ON T2.REQUEST_ID=T1.REQUEST_ID AND T2.NAME='owner_1'
  LEFT OUTER JOIN RICALM.VW_RQST_STRING_EXT T3
  ON T3.REQUEST_ID=T1.REQUEST_ID AND T3.NAME='owner_2'
    LEFT OUTER JOIN RICALM.VW_RQST_STRING_EXT T4
    ON T4.REQUEST_ID=T1.REQUEST_ID AND T4.NAME='owner_3'
WHERE T1.PROJECT_ID = 0  AND
(  T1.REQUEST_TYPE = 'Task' 
) AND
(T1.ISSOFTDELETED = 0) AND
(T1.REQUEST_ID <> -1 AND T1.REQUEST_ID IS NOT NULL))b

union all

select substr(c.o1,locate('_',c.o1,2)+1,locate('_',c.o1,2)-1)  as qwert from 

(SELECT DISTINCT T1.PROJECT_NAME,
       T1.REFERENCE_ID,
       T1.NAME AS URL1_title,
       T1.URL AS URL1,
       T1.REQUEST_TYPE,
       T2.VAL||'_' ||T3.VAL||'_'|| T4.VAL AS o1     
FROM RIDW.VW_REQUEST T1
LEFT OUTER JOIN RICALM.VW_RQST_STRING_EXT T2
ON T2.REQUEST_ID=T1.REQUEST_ID AND T2.NAME='owner_1'
  LEFT OUTER JOIN RICALM.VW_RQST_STRING_EXT T3
  ON T3.REQUEST_ID=T1.REQUEST_ID AND T3.NAME='owner_2'
    LEFT OUTER JOIN RICALM.VW_RQST_STRING_EXT T4
    ON T4.REQUEST_ID=T1.REQUEST_ID AND T4.NAME='owner_3'
WHERE T1.PROJECT_ID = 0  AND
(  T1.REQUEST_TYPE = 'Task' 
) AND
(T1.ISSOFTDELETED = 0) AND
(T1.REQUEST_ID <> -1 AND T1.REQUEST_ID IS NOT NULL))c
```

here is my modified query

For example

```
   select substr('abc_pqr_rams',1,LOCATE_IN_STRING('abc_pqr_rams','_')-1) from dual
    union all
    select substr('abc_pqr_rams',LOCATE_IN_STRING( 'abc_pqr_rams','_' )+1,LOCATE_IN_STRING('abc_pqr_rams','_')-1) from dual
    union all
    select substr('abc_pqr_rams',LOCATE_IN_STRING('abc_pqr_rams','_',1,2)+1,LOCATE_IN_STRING('abc_pqr_rams','_',1,2)-1) from dual
```

Comment: it returns nothing I have confusion which column to display?

Comment: what is the confusion?? Did you get my solution or not?

Comment: I am just starting to explore DB2 sql,i will put my query ,please correct ,where i done it something wrong @Rams

Comment: third substring not getting usingselect substr('abc_pqr_rams',locate('_','abc_pqr_rams',2)+1,locate('_','abc_pqr_rams',2)-1) from dual,it gives abc_ , pq @Rams

Comment: what is your db2 version... in my DB2 9.7 `instr` function is working... plz try to use 'instr'

Comment: instr is not recognized to database,hows it possible using locate?it will really helpful for me@Rams

Comment: @AmrutaRaut, I have edited it with `LOCATE_IN_STRING`